# How to round a column in a DataGridView VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am making an asp.net webpage using VB.Net that calculates the employee's yearly salary.

I have a GridView that displays a column with values of type double (they are double in the database "example: 66,556.91").

I want to round the values of this column so that I have 66,557 instead of 66,556.91.
I checked [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx), and used `{0:D}` and `{0:F0}` in the DataFormatString in the gridview taks - edit columns but no value was changed.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="C1" HeaderText="calculated taxes" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="C1" DataFormatString="{0:F0}" />
```

What do you suggest?

Comment: Is data is fetched from database?

Comment: Yes, the data is fetched from a MySQL database @JaydipJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your select command like this for salary column, this will perform rounding operation at database end.

```
SELECT ROUND(SalaryColumnName,0)
```

Comment: I was hoping not to use this since my sql statement is kinda complicated, but time wasn't on my side. It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a DataFormatString in your boundcolumn definition of {0:f0}  which will round your values to 0 decimal places.

Input Values

```
1
2.2
3.323
66556.91
```

Formatted Values
    1 
    2 
    3 
    66557

Comment: I've seen that, sadly it didn't work when it supposed to work

Comment: Are you definitely sure your source data is in a Decimal data type? I ran the {0:f0} dataformatstring through a test web app and it worked as described.

Comment: Sorry had to mention that my source is in double type not decimal, this makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

```
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
  ' Call Math.Round on this Double.
Dim before As Double = 123.45
Dim after1 As Double = Math.Round(before, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
Dim after2 As Double = Math.Round(before, 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven)
Dim after3 As Double = Math.Round(before)

Console.WriteLine(before)
Console.WriteLine(after1)
Console.WriteLine(after2)
Console.WriteLine(after3)
Console.WriteLine()

  ' Use on this Decimal.
Dim before2 As Decimal = 125.101
Dim after4 As Decimal = Math.Round(before2)
Dim after5 As Decimal = Math.Round(before2, 1)

Console.WriteLine(before2)
Console.WriteLine(after4)
Console.WriteLine(after5)
End Sub
End Module
```

---

```
Output

123.45
123.5
123.4
123

125.101
125
125.1
```